# CORS error while connecting react frontend with express/node backend hosted in netlify

Tags: javascript, express, deployment, cors, netlify

First off, everything works when both of them are in localhost. I hosted the backend in netlify and everything stops working.

- I have used cors() and enabled all websites and headers.
- I have used _headers file to configure cors also

When I hit the /api/test endpoint, the frontend receives the json response and displays it without any problem. But when I hit any other resource, i get CORS error.

This is my netlify/functions/api.js file

```
const express = require("express"); 
const app = express();
const cors= require('cors')

const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
const postRoute = require("../../routes/post"); 
const commentRoute = require("../../routes/comment");
const getPostsRoute = require("../../routes/getPosts"); 
const getCommentsRoute = require("../../routes/getComments"); 
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
const serverless = require('serverless-http'); 
const getTestsRoute = require("../../routes/getTest"); 


exports.handler = function async(event , context) { 
    app.use(cors()); 
    app.options('*', cors());     dotenv.config(); 
    
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
    
    mongoose.connect( 
        process.env.MONGO_URL)
 
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use("/api/post", postRoute);
    app.use("/api/getPosts", getPostsRoute);
    
    app.use("/api/comment", commentRoute); 
    app.use("/api/getComments", getCommentsRoute); 
    app.use("/api/test", getTestsRoute);
    
    // app.listen(8800, () => { 
    //     console.log ("Backend server is running at port 8000"); 
    // })

    return serverless(app)(event,context); 

};
```

This is my netlify.toml . In the netlify.toml file, I have added almost all the code I could find on the internet that might solve the problem. But nothing seems to work to me.

```
[functions]
  external_node_modules = ["express"]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[[redirects]]
  from = "/api/*"
  to = "/.netlify/functions/api/:splat" 
  status = 200
  force = true
  headers = {X-From = "Netlify"}
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "http://my-service.com/api/:splat" 
  status = 200 
[[headers]]
  for = "/*"
  [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

This is my getTest route thats working fine without cors error

```
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
    "test api is working": "middleware being used",
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my getPosts endpoint that is not working.

```
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find(); // Retrieve all posts from the database
    const headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'
    };

    // Include headers in the response
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, posts, headers });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "An error occurred while fetching posts" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am stuck on this problem for days. Someone, please help me out